# How to reverse the x-axis in a serial Amcharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, reverse, amcharts

I have the following Chart:
[image]

I want to reverse the x axis to become from 2004 to 2018. Which mean 2016 2014 ... 2006

What I tried to do:

1- Reversed the dataProvider `"dataProvider": this.state.historicalData.reverse()`
But didn't work I got the following Chart:
[image]

2- I added reversed attribute to valueAxes object in the Amcharts config

```
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "right",
  },{
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "reversed": true,
    "position": "bottom",
  }]
```

But that didn't work because it's a Serial Chart as we mentioned [here](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-react/issues/85)

So, Any solution instead of changing the chart type to `XY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Descending dates are not supported in v3 at all in parsed date axes](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#parseDates), even in XY charts since it follows the same logic with date-based value axes.

You can either simply not parse dates in your category axis and reverse your data like in your first attempt or use v4, which allows you to render your date axes in descending order.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Can you explain more about your suggestion "simply not parse dates in your category axis and reverse your data like in your first attempt"

Comment: Set `parseDates: false` then `this.state.historicalData.reverse()` will work. You lose out on date formatting, so create a [`labelFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#labelFunction) if you need to format your axis labels.